# What is the term for increasing remuneration of a person on account of him/her being paid less than their counterparts erstwhile.

Tags: terminology

What do you call the action by an employer where he/she increases the salary of person a to the level of person b on grounds that person a and b are performing at the same level but person a was being paid less than person b earlier.

Comment: ........justice

Comment: The salary of the person is said to be brought "on par" with the others/ with the standards. There's a term called *pay-parity*.

Answer (score 2):

In case of two employees, it's **equalizing** their salaries.

If this is done company-wide, it will be **normalizing** the salaries, following positions and performance.